# Distributing Giving out Quarters Suplus and Shortage Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Amy, Betty, and Chloe have some quarters. Amy gives some of her quarters to Betty and Chloe, making their quarters doubled. Then Betty dos the same thing, making Amy and Chloe's quarters doubled. And Chloe does the same thing, making Amy's and Betty's quarters doubled. After all these, the number of quarters of each one is 8. So in the beginning, how much quarters does everyone have?

The equations that I get seem overly complicated, so I need the formula for this kind of problem. I got

A=Amy's amount
B=Betty's amount
C=Chloe's amount 
$(((A-B-C)2)2)$=8
$((2B-(A-B-C))2)=8$

$4C-(2[A-B-C])-2B-[A-B-C]=8$

Comment: If they all end with $8$ quarters, the right side of each of those equations should be $8$ not $A$, $B$, or $C$. Also, if they ended with $24$ quarters, they started with $24$ quarters, so $A+B+C = 24$, which might be simpler than the last equation you wrote. For an even simpler solution, look at Andre Nicolas' answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use equations: *work backwards*. As a start, note that before C's gift, A and B had $4$ each, and C had $16$. Continue.

Comment: What is it just says, instead of each has 8, it just says they have the same amount?

Comment: If same amount, the same argument works, though naturally the answer depends on the amount. Either let the same amount be $k$. Then before the last step it was $(k/2,k/2,2k)$. Or, better, *recycle* your answer for $8$. If the answer for $8$ is $(a,b,c)$, then the answer for $k$ is $(ka/8,kb/8,kc/8)$.

Comment: I don't really know that, so I asked a question that had that. <br> http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/913625/sharing-and-distributing-surplus-and-shortage-problem

Comment: It is a somewhat different problem. A similar working backwards strategy will work. so will equations. I will leave it to someone else to answer, but urge you to work it out yourself before someone does. If (unlikely!) no answer appears before tomorrow, and you have not solved it, and I get a message to that effect, I will answer.

Comment: I don't have time to sit around until tommorrow though

Comment: Well, then perhaps earlier. There will be divisibility considerations involved.

Comment: I've been trying to do it but I can't seem to be able to figure out how. Can you please answer my question Andre Nicolas?